# Pass Nullable T to method

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
public void AddVariable<T>(String name, T value) where T : struct {
}
```

This method accepts the following:

```
AddVariable("Price", 2387);
```

But does not accept

```
AddVariable("Name", "A name");
```

I want T to be only basic types like int, string, boolean ... That's why I used struct. But I think I need it to be nullable to accept String.

How can I set my method to accept nullable basic types?

And is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Um, `String` is a class. It's not a `Nullable<T>` at all. If your method needs to support string values, you can't have the `where : struct` constraint.

Comment: a function overload may be appropriate.

Comment: What do you do in `AddVariable` that it can only support "primitive" types?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such constraint.  The only common base types between `string` and `int` are object, `IConvertible`, and `IComparable`.  You could do type checking at run-time, or use overloads for each supported type (with a private generic method if it would save on code duplication):

```
private void AddVariable<T>(String name, T value) 
{
    // common code here
}

public void AddVariable(String name, int value) 
{
    AddVariable<int>(name, value);
}

public void AddVariable(String name, string value) 
{
    AddVariable<string>(name, value);
}
```

etc.